# Пунктуация в предложении с тремя «и»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, и

> Однако на неустанное стремление этих людей к созидательной жизни
> указывают **и расположение, и устройство** их поселений, **и** непременное
> **возвращение** к мирному труду, как только минует военная угроза.

Если в предложении три "и", два из которых объединяют пару...
Как правило называется, где на него поглядеть?

"Устройство" и "расположение" не нуждаются в запятой — как же ж жить?

Answer (score 1):

*Однако на неустанное стремление этих людей к созидательной жизни указывают **и расположение и устройство их поселений, и непременное возвращение к мирному труду**, как только минует военная угроза.*

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101

9. **Парные группы однородных членов, в свою очередь, могут соединяться повторяющимся союзом:** Среди рек есть и большие и малые, и спокойные и буйные, и быстрые и медленные; Снаряды рвались и близко и далеко, и справа и слева.

Comment: Шаронушка, не то правило! У тебя три пары, моё - потерянное - другое! Про пару среди непар.

Comment: А какая разница? Думаю, что Розенталь разрешает повторяющимися союзами И...И соединять однородные члены с ЛЮБЫМ составом, в том числе пару однородных членов и третий член.

Comment: С запятой всё разрешилось, убрали, но точно есть правило о моём случае, а это не оно.

Comment: Есть только правило в п.8 о более тесной связи двух однородных членов по отношению к третьему, но там вообще нет запятых, так как союзы неповторяющиеся. А у Розенталя вряд ли есть другое правило про повторяющиеся союзы, если только у кого-нибудь еще.

Comment: Шаронушка, найди, плиииз! Через другие ключевые слова. У меня не вышло. Но я его видела лет десять назад на Ответах Майла.

Comment: У туточки: https://popravilam.com/blog/063-soyuz-i-povtoryaetsya-no-zapyataya-ne-nuzhna.html

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что подходящее разъяснение нашлось в журнале ["Русский язык"](https://rus.1sept.ru/article.php?ID=200401503):

> Бывают сложные предложения, части которых можно считать однородными, поскольку они соединены сочинительной связью и при этом имеют какой-либо общий элемент: **общий член предложения**, общее придаточное или общее главное предложение для двух или нескольких придаточных. На такие предложения распространяются правила пунктуации при однородных членах, в частности, **не ставится запятая между однородными частями**, если они соединены одиночным союзом *и, или, либо.*

*Однако на неустанное стремление этих людей к созидательной жизни указывают **и*** (1) *расположение **и*** (2) *устройство их поселений, **и*** (3) *непременное возвращение к мирному труду, как только минует военная угроза.*

В нашем предложении союз (2) соединяет однородные "расположение" и "устройство" (общим членом является "поселений") — запятая между ними не требуется; союзы (1) и (3) являются повторяющимися — запятая перед союзом (3) нужна (по правилу [о повторяющихся союзах](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=124#pp124)).

Comment: Римуля, спасибо; вот мой случай, но меня из "источника" выгнал Касперский: "Очень сложным моментом будет применение такого пункта правил: "если два однородных члена предложения с союзом «и» образуют тесно связанную по смыслу пару, соединенную союзом «и» с третьим однородным членом, запятая не ставится".

Правило предполагает, что при тесной связи двух членов (как правило, сказуемых) они образуют пару с одиночным «и», к которой при помощи второго одиночного «и, присоединен новый элемент.

Например: Маша пришла домой и переоделась и стала раскладывать купленные подарки по пакетикам".

Comment: Я жду правила из Розенталя, поищите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Симпатишная ссылочка: https://popravilam.com/blog/063-soyuz-i-povtoryaetsya-no-zapyataya-ne-nuzhna.html